# Get post content doesn't display correctly with Visual Composer

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, visual-composer

I have the following issue. I'm using Visual Composer for my website content. I decided to rebuild my header with VC too.
I created a page called Header and created the header template there/
I've added the following code into my header to display the created page content (Header) there:

```
<?php 
    $id=14; 
    $post = get_post($id); 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
    echo $content;  
?>
```

But it doesn't work correctly. Everything is fine with its content (texts, links, menu items etc) but it doesn't display background colors, paddings etc.
What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Please check below link. Hope this will help full. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9667/get-wordpress-post-content-by-post-id

Comment: Thanks, I saw this page recently. Unfortunately, I didn't find the solution for my case there.

Comment: @Morgari could you `var_dump($content)` and post the output?

Comment: @qskane could you, please, provide some more information? What should I do? php is not my strong side :(